# Receiving name error while running a python file

Tags: python, machine-learning

Receiving below error when I am trying to run the python file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sample JSON:

```
{
    "intents": [{
        "tag": "greeting",
        "patterns": ["Hi there", "How are you", "Is anyone there?", "Hey", "Hola", "Hello", "Good day"],
        "responses": ["Hello, thanks for asking", "Good to see you again", "Hi there, how can I help?"],
        "context": [""]
    }, {
        "tag": "goodbye",
        "patterns": ["Bye", "See you later", "Goodbye", "Nice chatting to you, bye", "Till next time"],
        "responses": ["See you!", "Have a nice day", "Bye! Come back again soon."],
        "context": [""]
    }]
}
```

There is no true keyword present in `intents.json`.

```py
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import random
import pandas as pd
words=[]
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_words = ['?', '!']
data_file = open('intents.json').read()
intents = json.loads(data_file)
for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        #tokenize each word
        w = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(w)
        #add documents in the corpus
        documents.append((w, intent['tag']))
        # add to our classes list
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])

import nltk
#  lemmatize, lower each word and remove duplicates
words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower()) for w in words if w not in ignore_words]
words = sorted(list(set(words)))
# sort classes
classes = sorted(list(set(classes)))
# documents = combination between patterns and intents
print (len(documents), "documents")
# classes = intents
print (len(classes), "classes", classes)
# words = all words, vocabulary
print (len(words), "unique lemmatized words", words)
pickle.dump(words,open('words.pkl','wb'))
pickle.dump(classes,open('classes.pkl','wb'))



# create our training data
training = []
# create an empty array for our output
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)
# training set, bag of words for each sentence
for doc in documents:
    # initialize our bag of words
    bag = []
    # list of tokenized words for the pattern
    pattern_words = doc[0]
    # lemmatize each word - create base word, in attempt to represent related words
    pattern_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in pattern_words]
    # create our bag of words array with 1, if word match found in current pattern
for w in words:
    bag.append(1) if w in pattern_words else bag.append(0)
    # output is a '0' for each tag and '1' for current tag (for each pattern)
    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(doc[1])] = 1
    training.append([bag, output_row])
# shuffle our features and turn into np.array
random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)
# create train and test lists. X - patterns, Y - intents
train_x = list(training[:,0])
train_y = list(training[:,1])
print("Training data created")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "ChatBot_Application.ipynb", line 16, in 
> "scrolled": true
> NameError: name 'true' is not defined

Comment: Add a sample of the data to your post from the `intents.json` file. Also, did you just try above two lines of code or it's more? I asked because you tagged this question as `machine-learning`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's built-in boolean constants are `True` and `False` and case-sensitive, [link to the documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#False). The error message clearly states in your `ChatBot_Application.ipynb` file in line `16`, you have an invalid keyword. So, in your notebook file, you have used `true` instead of `True`. Otherwise one of your imported libraries has this issue.

**Running iPython Notebook in Command Line**

From question author's comment:

> I am trying to run it through command prompt using the below command: python ChatBot_Application.ipynb

If you are running an iPython file directly from the terminal, you need to install a library like [runipy](https://pypi.org/project/runipy/). Install it by running `pip install runipy` in command line. Then you can run your notebook like this: `runipy ChatBot_Application.ipynb`.

**From Question Author's Updated Code**

As you can see `nltk.download('punkt')` needs to used and run in your script once as it downloads the required `Sentence Tokenizer`. Link to the updated code and working demo is [here](https://repl.it/repls/VillainousNaturalMacroinstruction)

Code:

```
import json
import nltk

## Need this to download Punkt Sentence Tokenizer
## Use it once, then comment the following line
nltk.download('punkt')

words=[]
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_words = ['?', '!']
data_file = open('intents.json').read()
intents = json.loads(data_file)

for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        #tokenize each word
        w = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(w)
        #add documents in the corpus
        documents.append((w, intent['tag']))
        # add to our classes list
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])

print(words)
print(classes)
print(documents)
```

Screenshot:

[image: update code json output]

**Sample Code to Load JSON:**

```py
import json

data_file = open('intents.json').read()
intents = json.loads(data_file)

print(intents)
```

I took your initial code and run it in `Repl.it`, [link](https://repl.it/repls/GrandiosePerfectWebsites). You can see it's producing output as expected.

[image: json output python]

Comment: {"intents": [
        {"tag": "greeting",
         "patterns": ["Hi there", "How are you", "Is anyone there?","Hey","Hola", "Hello", "Good day"],
         "responses": ["Hello, thanks for asking", "Good to see you again", "Hi there, how can I help?"],
         "context": [""]
        },
        {"tag": "goodbye",
         "patterns": ["Bye", "See you later", "Goodbye", "Nice chatting to you, bye", "Till next time"],
         "responses": ["See you!", "Have a nice day", "Bye! Come back again soon."],
         "context": [""]
        }]}

Comment: There is no true keyword used inside the intents.json file.

Comment: I didn't mean your JSON file has `true` keyword. The error message clearly states in your `ChatBot_Application.ipynb` file inline 16, you have an invalid keyword. Please post your code from that notebook. Thanks for JSON content, I updated my answer you still can see from this [link](https://repl.it/repls/GrandiosePerfectWebsites#main.py), it loads fine using your sample code you shared initially in your question.

Comment: I am trying to run it through command prompt using the below command:
python ChatBot_Application.ipynb

Comment: If you are running an iPython file directly from the terminal, you need to install a library like [runipy](https://pypi.org/project/runipy/). Install it by running `pip install runipy` in command line. Then you can run your notebook like this: `runipy ChatBot_Application.ipynb` Running it like `python ChatBot_Application.ipynb` won't work. It's not a Python script. I have updated my answer with every possible scenario.

Comment: Link to the newest code is here: https://repl.it/repls/VillainousNaturalMacroinstruction

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. That error is gone now. My command was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

True should have a capital T; python is trying to find a variable called true, rather than using the boolean value

Comment: I am not returning any boolean value, just reading a json file.

Answer (score 0):

true should have capital T such as True in python

Comment: I am not returning any boolean value, just reading a json file. 

for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        #tokenize each word
        w = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(w)
        #add documents in the corpus
        documents.append((w, intent['tag']))
        # add to our classes list
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])